# RSSI RFID unable to read signal strength

Tags: c#, windows, windows-ce, rfid, rssi

I am trying to read RFID signals on a [Windows CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) device. I have searched Google and found something related to RSSI. But nothing is present in the RFID API regarding RSSI.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: what model of RFID reader you are using?

If I'm assuming correctly, you probably have an MC9090 (or equivalent) from Motorola/Symbol

If that's the case, their SDK (called EMDK) includes documentation for several RSSI related classes and properties including RssiRangeFilter.

The most recent revision for .NET developers is [EMDK v2.6 Update 2](http://support.symbol.com/support/dynamickc.do?externalId=13480&sliceId=&command=show&forward=nonthreadedKC&kcId=13480&userId=37)

To download the documentation for the API, right click and save [this file](https://docs.symbol.com/downloads/Help-M-020605-UP2C.zip). On Windows 7, it may not display properly at first, so if that happens, check out [this solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2021383).

Hope that helps!

Comment: actually its a windows device of chainway. [see this](http://www.directindustry.com/prod/shenzhen-chainway-information-technology-co-ltd/hand-held-rfid-reader-writers-70134-741835.html)